# How to make my JSON work with a Gijgo grid in Django/Python?

Tags: python, json, django

I tried the code below to be able to show my database records in a [Gijgo](http://gijgo.com/grid/configuration) grid. Unfortunately it doesn't work, because Gijgo by default expects JSON data without keys.

As far as I know there are two options to solve this problem:

- Get rid of the keys (`model`, `pk`, `fields`) in JSON, which is accepted by Gijgo
- Configure Gijgo to understand my JSON structure (couldn't find any information about this approach)

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

**Code**

```
demand = Demand.objects.filter(week__number=request.GET["weeknumber"], week__year=request.GET["weekyear"])
response = serializers.serialize("json", demand)
return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')

[{"model": "demand", "pk": 4, "fields": {"week": 3, "model": 1, "product": 3, "type": 7, "build": 1, "sdna": 1234, "rcna": 234234, "sdeu": 3333, "rceu": 433, "ssd": 53, "src": 63, "notes": "fafd"}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .render() method in order to modify your server response to javascript array that is usable by the gijgo grid. You can see an example at http://gijgo.com/grid/methods/render

You can also use http://gijgo.com/grid/configuration/mapping.dataField and http://gijgo.com/grid/configuration/mapping.totalRecordsField if you modify the response on the server and want to return the info in custom field names.